# Maven - Will a plugin defined in a dependency be included?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Say repo `a` has a plugin `x` via `<plugin><plugin>`, and  repo `b` include `a` as a dependency via `<dependency></dependency>`.

So, in repo `b`, will plugin `x` be inherited / included, and able to execute its goals?

Previous, I thought it's not, but by accident, I found it's actually included according to the test.

After searching on google for a while, didn't get a clear explanation. Any one help to clarify the behavior?

---

### @Update - pom config

*(as requested from comment, I would add pom config)*

---

**Part 1 - original config from question**

**(1-1)** `pom.xml` from *(parent)* project **p**:

Declare plugin version in `<pluginManagement>`:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.905</version>
      <executions>
        <!-- <execution> -->
        <!-- <id>analyse</id> -->
        <!-- <goals> -->
        <!-- <goal>sonar</goal> -->
        <!-- </goals> -->
        <!-- <phase>install</phase> -->
        <!-- </execution> -->
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Define plugin configuration in `<profiles>`:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonar</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:5757</sonar.host.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

**(1-2)** `pom.xml` from project **a** *(which use project **p** as parent)*:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**(1-3)** `pom.xml` from project **b** *(which also use project **p** as parent, and contains project **a** as dependency)*:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, the situation is, project **b** didn't include plugin `sonar-maven-plugin` directly using `<plugin>` *(despite it inherit `<pluginManagement>` from project **p**)*.
It still could execute the goal `mvn sonar:sonar` successfully, so it seems to get the plugin work due to it has a `<dependency>` of project **a**.

---

**Part 2 - config from further test mentioned in comment**

**(2-1)** `pom.xml` from *(parent)* project **p**

same as **(1-1)**

**(2-2)** `pom.xml` from project **a**

remove the `<plugin>` part, and replace with dependency of the plugin via `<dependency>`:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.905</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**(2-3)** `pom.xml` from project **b**

same as **(1-3)**

And, now both project `a` and `b` could still execute the goal via `mvn sonar:sonar` successfully, without a `<plugin>` part.

Comment: If a plugin defines dependencies those dependencies will be downloaded to local cache and will be available for the plugin on it's own classpath.

Comment: @khmarbaise So, you mean as long as the plugin's dependency is available, then could execute those goals?

Comment: To execute a goal of a plugin all dependencies of the plugin must be available....

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, I did a test, remove the `<plugin></plugin>` part, instead add a `<dependency></dependency>` while keep the configurations, the plugin still works, seems as long as the dependencies & configuration/profile are available, the plugin can be used, event though there is no `<plugin></plugin>` in `<plugins></plugins>`.

Comment: Can you show your pom file? Apart from that I don't understand your latest comments?

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the question, please check the `@Update` part.